# Javascript clearTimeout() not working

Tags: javascript, jscript

When I try to clearTimeout(), the timeout just continues.
Code:

```
function autoSlides(x) {
    var timeOut;
    if (x == 1) {
        plusSlides(1);
        document.getElementById("switch").onclick = function () { autoSlides(2) };
        timeOut = setTimeout(function () { autoSlides(1) }, 4000);
    } else if (x == 2) {
        clearTimeout(timeOut);
        document.getElementById("switch").onclick = function () { autoSlides(1) };
    }
}
```

Comment: `timeOut` is not in scope for your `else if` block. You initialize it at function scope but assign it only in your `if` block.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because you're declaring `timeOut` inside of the function. That means that you aren't using the same value you thought you saved earlier.

```js
function autoSlides(x) {
  var timeOut; // Initialized to `undefined`
  if (x === 1) {
    timeOut = setTimeout(function() {
      console.log('Look, the timeout finished');
    }, 1000);
  } else if (x === 2) {
    // Remember: this is a new timeout variable
    // So this really means `clearTimeout(undefined)`
    clearTimeout(timeOut);
  }
}

autoSlides(1);
autoSlides(2);
```

What you need to do is save the timeout ID somewhere outside of the function.

```js
var timeOut; // Won't be reset every time the function is called
function autoSlides(x) {
  if (x === 1) {
    timeOut = setTimeout(function() {
      console.log('Look, the timeout never finishes');
    }, 1000);
  } else if (x === 2) {
    // The value was saved last time
    clearTimeout(timeOut);
    console.log('cleared the timeout');
  }
}

autoSlides(1);
autoSlides(2);
```

Answer (score 1):

`timeOut` is a variable local to `autoSlides`.

`autoSlides` has an if statement so it will either:

- Assign a value to `timeOut`
- Try to use `timeOut` to clear a timeout

Since it never does both, the value of `timeOut` will always be `undefined` in the second case.

If you want to reuse the variable across multiple calls to the `autoSlides` function then you need to declare it **outside**, not inside, `autoSlides`.

Answer (score 0):

You can assign "timeout" to outside of the function scope. One option is to attach it to the global "window" object if your using client-side javascript:

```
window.timeOut = setTimeout(function () { autoSlides(1) }, 4000);

clearTimeout(window.timeOut);
```